# i want to display ref_number which doesnt have or_cancelled 0. thanks

Tags: php

i have two table   tbl_particular,tbl_collection

```
tbl_particular contains
ref_number             or_number
DISCO-X-2016-0162        333333
DISCO-X-2016-0162        888888


tbl_collection contains
ref_number             or_number            or_cancelled
DISCO-X-2016-0162      888888                    0
DISCO-X-2016-0162      333333                    1

SELECT DISTINCT tbl_particular.ref_number AS data1,
             tbl_particular.or_number AS data2
             FROM tbl_particular
             JOIN tbl_collection
             ON tbl_particular.or_number=tbl_collection.or_number
            WHERE EXISTS(SELECT ref_number FROM tbl_particular WHERE
            tbl_collection.or_cancelled=1)


output:

data1                  data2
DISCO-X-2016-0162      333333
```

supposed there's no output because DISCO-X-2016-0162 is having or_cancelled 0 .

need help

Answer (score 0):

Use following query to get expected output

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_particular.ref_number AS data1,
                 tbl_particular.or_number AS data2
                 FROM tbl_collection , tbl_particular 
                WHERE tbl_particular.or_number=tbl_collection.or_number and tbl_particular.ref_number NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ref_number FROM tbl_collection where or_cancelled =0 )
```

explanation:

```
sub query : 
(SELECT DISTINCT ref_number FROM tbl_collection where or_cancelled =0 )  will give list of ref_numbers which is having or_cancelled =0

main query :
  SELECT DISTINCT tbl_particular.ref_number AS data1,
             tbl_particular.or_number AS data2
             FROM tbl_collection , tbl_particular 
            WHERE tbl_particular.or_number=tbl_collection.or_number and tbl_particular.ref_number NOT IN (result of sub query) 

will give other then sub query resulted ref_numbers so you will get empty result set
```

expected output:

```
empty result set
```

Comment: OUTPUT:  DISCO-X-2016-0162      333333     (its should not return the 333333 because DISCO-X-2016-0162 have or_cancelled 0 in or_number 888888)

Comment: if data1(DISCO-X-2016-0162) has or_cancelled 0 in tbl_collection, it should not output the DISCO-X-2016-0162. thanks.

Comment: sorry it will not give that output if or_cancelled= 0 in tbl_collection ;  i will explain how it will be (SELECT DISTINCT ref_number FROM tbl_collection where or_cancelled ==0 ) you will get DISCO-X-2016-0162; and remaining query will execute other then DISCO-X-2016-0162. so you will get output as empty not  DISCO-X-2016-0162      333333

Comment: still, its not what i want in output. i want to display ref_number from tbl_particular that have or_cancelled=1 in tbl_particular. thanks

Comment: @mab , after small modification it is working well now check. i have tried too. it will working well

Comment: still, not what i want. but thanks anyway. its really help me to get what i really want in the output.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
SELECT
 tbl_particular.ref_number,
 tbl_particular.or_number
FROM tbl_particular
INNER JOIN tbl_collection
 ON tbl_particular.or_number=tbl_collection.or_number
WHERE tbl_collection.ref_number NOT IN (
 SELECT ref_number FROM tbl_collection WHERE or_cancelled = 1 GROUP BY ref_number
);
```

Comment: OUTPUT:  DISCO-X-2016-0162      333333     (its should not return the 333333 because DISCO-X-2016-0162 have or_cancelled 0 in or_number 888888)

Comment: if data1(DISCO-X-2016-0162) has or_cancelled 0 in tbl_collection, it should not output the DISCO-X-2016-0162. thanks.

Comment: still, its not what i want in output. i want to display ref_number from tbl_particular that have or_cancelled=1 in tbl_particular. thanks